# MPI4PY strange OS error

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, mpi4py

I have a complex MPI4PY script, that gives a seemingly impossible error.

The important part of the script:

```
for rnd in range(50):
    if rnd > 0:
        WEIGHT_FILE = '{}/weights_{}.wts'.format(WORK_DIR, rnd - 1)
        WORK_DIR = '{}'.format(rnd)

    if PROCESS_NUM == 0:
        if not os.path.isdir(WORK_DIR):
            os.mkdir(WORK_DIR)
    ....
```

So after the second iteration i get `OS Error, cannot create directory, directory exists`. How is this possible? If the directory exists, if should not create it. `PROCESS_NUM` is the MPI rank, so only one process should try to create it. Is there some kind of race condition, or locking error? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to found the answer, and i was deep in the architecture, not related to python.

I was using `SLURM` distribution manager with `mpich`, and on one of the nodes there was an installation of `open-mpi` as well alongside `mpich` causing some trouble. The numbering of the cores on that node was 0/1 for all allocations, causing a race condition in the script cause multiple cores got the same `PROCESS_NUM`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the full path name before checking:

```
if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(full_path, WORK_DIR)):
```

Let's use:

```
os.makedirs(WORK_DIR, exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: My variable `WORK_DIR` is an explicit full path, also if i just pop open a command line and simply run the `if os.path.isdir ... print("asd")` it check out, so i am sure the directory exists. The default value looks like this: `WORK_DIR = '/home/username/ITERATION_0' and it exists.
`

Comment: Are U sure the error is in line 'os.mkdir(WORK_DIR)', becouse first U create variable WEIGHT_FILE and U use previous WORK_DIR(from previous iteration).

Comment: I think i was able to pinpoint the problem, i wrote an answer, i am testing if that is really the case, but it is surely not related to variable creation.